# Removing words from lemmatisation dictionary/updating lemma dictionary in textstem

Tags: r, nlp, sentiment-analysis, stemming, lemmatization

I am using the textstem package to lemmatise words in some responses. However there is one word (spotting) which I do not wan't to be included, and reduced to "spot". I want it to remain as spotting. How might I be able to do this? Do I need to make a custom dictionary? Currently doing:

```
lemmatize_strings(df, dictionary = lexicon::hash_lemmas)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own dictionary where you remove the token `spotting`

```
# hash_lemmas is a datatable, so you can use column name token instead hash_lemmas$token
my_lex <- lexicon::hash_lemmas[!token == "spotting", ]

df_lemmatized <- lemmatize_strings(df, dictionary = my_lex)
```

Or if you want to do it without creating your own lexicon:

```
df_lemmatized <- lemmatize_strings(df, dictionary = lexicon::hash_lemmas[!token == "spotting", ])
```